# Ansible hangs while applying firewall rules

Tags: iptables, ansible

I've tried a number of ways to do this. I have a few firewall rules that are a little more complex then the ufw module supports. Though, I could probably use that module if I really have to.

So far I have tried the following:
1. putting my rules in a shell script and executing it asynchronously. Seems to work some of the time. The rules get applied, but ansible hangs.

```
- name: Apply firewall rules
  shell: iptables.sh
  async: 45
  poll: 5
```

2. Putting my rules in a rule file and then using iptables-restore < rules to apply them. The rules get applied, but ansible hangs. (this is the method I am currently trying)

> ```
> - name: Set up the v4 firewall rules
>   template:
>     src=templates/firewallv4_template.j2
>     dest=/tmp/rules.v4
>     owner=vagrant group=vagrant mode=0644
> - name: Apply firewall rules
>   shell: iptables-restore < /tmp/rules.v4
>   async: 45
>   poll: 5
> ```

3. Used iptables-persistent but kept getting ipv6 rule failures and got tired of that.

Has anyone had any success with this?

Comment: Why are you doing it async? Does it take that long to run? Does it work if you run it sequentially?

Comment: I tried async because I thought that the connection might be a work around.

Comment: One of your rule must lock you out of the box. So Ansible is not able to continue its job. I created a role to ease the management of iptables rules: https://github.com/mikegleasonjr/ansible-role-firewall

Comment: It maybe because your existing SSH connection is getting dropped when new rules are applied. 
[https://www.shysecurity.com/post/20160427-Ansible%20iptables%20workaround][1]


  [1]: https://www.shysecurity.com/post/20160427-Ansible%20iptables%20workaround

Answer (score 0):

Use a rule file, and then use iptables restore like this:

```
- name: Do not wait for a response
  shell: >
    iptables-restore /tmp/rules.v4
  become: true
  async: 10
  poll: 0
```